# What type is the connector?

Tags: connector

I can't find type of this connector.
Space between pins is 1.27 mm.
And it has 6 pins.
What type is this connector?

[image: image 0]
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]

Comment: Where did you look?

Comment: @AliChen It is on RS485 device.